# why this error 'Access Denied Unable to write to /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/.'

Tags: matlab

I am trying to install `matlab` in Ubuntu but getting this error:

```
Access Denied Unable to write to /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/
```

Comment: Probably current permissions don't allow for access. Check current users access level or try `sudo` if required.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I don't think so. The OP here isn't telling us what they are actually trying to do, but reading between the lines it looks like they just didn't run it with sudo. The dupe target won't help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what command gave you that error. We can't guess.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the root privilege in order to write or edit a file in any directory in `/usr/local/`. The mentioned error occurs because you do not have root privilege and you are trying to install it in a directory other than your home folder.

A quick solution is to install MATLAB on your home directory.

Comment: sudo chown -R $LOGNAME: /path/to/installation/directory if this doesnt solve  sudo chmod u+rwx -R /path/to/installation/directory

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo ./install` from the folder containing the installation file. It worked for me.